# Creating a dynamically generated popup with xslt/xml/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt

I've been banging my head against the wall for awhile with this. It seems so simple yet nothing I try seems to work out, maybe some expert eyes can shed light on the problem.

I have a collection of xml documents (they are actually TEI encoded letters). Each xml document contains references to persons. These references are denoted with a persName tag. Each persName is also identified by a ref attribute. There is also an include in each letter that pulls in biographical information about each persName.

What I'd like to do, is to allow for each name in the letter to become a clickable link that would open up a new window or popup, and in that window would be the correct biographical information about the person that you just clicked on.

Here is the XSL that finds persNames with refs and wraps them in an a tag with a bit of js to open a new window (I'm not married to a new window opening, if some genius out there knows of a way to make this display in a nice lightbox or something, even better).

```
   <xsl:template match="*:persName[@ref]">
  <!-- surround each persname with an a tag with a specific ID -->
  <head>
  </head>
  <a>
     <xsl:attribute name="href">javascript://</xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
        <xsl:text>javascript:window.open('</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$xtfURL"/><xsl:value-of select="$dynaxmlPath"/><xsl:text>?docId=</xsl:text><xsl:value-of
           select="$docId"/><xsl:text>;doc.view=personpopup;?pers=</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@ref"></xsl:value-of><xsl:text>','Personography','width=800,height=400,modal=yes,alwaysRaised=yes')</xsl:text>
     </xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:value-of select="*"></xsl:value-of>
  </a>
```

When the link is clicked we go to the personpopup template shown here

```
   <xsl:template name="personpopup">
  <html>
     <head>         
        <!-- SCRIPT TO GRAB PERS FROM URL AND MATCH IT IN THE PERSONOGRAPHY -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

           var currenturl = window.location.href;
           var currentperson = currenturl.substring(currenturl.indexOf('pers=#') + 6);

           document.write(currentperson);

        </script>
        <title></title>
     </head>
     <body>
        <p>
           <h3><xsl:value-of select="/*/*:text/*:body/*:div[@type='ographies']/*:listPerson/*:person[@ref'personclicked']/*:info"></xsl:value-of></h3>
           <a>
              <xsl:attribute name="href">javascript://</xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="onClick">
                 <xsl:text>javascript:window.close('popup')</xsl:text>
              </xsl:attribute>
              Close this Window
           </a>
        </p>
     </body>
  </html>
```

The js code in the header was part of an attempt get the ref variable over to the new window. The js code "knows" who is clicked and will display the correct ref when the new window pops up but I'm unsure of how I would be able to make use of that variable in order to pull the correct info for the person that was clicked. Any ideas?

Comment: What would a day working with xslt be without some head-banging?

Comment: The issue is that your javascript is going to run AFTER the XSLT transformation has been done, not during the transformation as you expect. That is to say, the XML is transformed by XSLT into HTML + Javascript, and then the browser runs this JavaScript. But by that point, the XSLT is all done with.

Comment: What you could do is pass the person id as a parameter to the XSLT before it runs, but how to do this depends on what current platform you are using to do the transformation? (.Net? PHP? JavaScript?). Alternatively, if there are not many people records involved, you could perhaps render them all out at once, but make them all hidden, using CSS. Then your current javascript could run to just show the one you require.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim, I'd love to be able to pass the person ref to the template being called but I can't for the life of me get it to work. I create the param in the first template, and call the personpopup template with xsl:with-param but that param just doesn't seem to be able to make it to the new template intact, it just returns blank.